# Fedora UEFI grub theme not being properly set

Tags: fedora, grub2, uefi

What I do to apply the grub theme is:

Add the following to /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub2/themes/system/theme.txt"
```

Then run the following command to regenerate config file:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

And finally I reboot, but I get no theme. Has anyone encountered this before and know a way around this?

Comment: It's assumed that the "theme" is provided from the fedora repos?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything is right, but if you take a closer look at `/etc/default/grub` you will find the line:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
```

Comment it out, build again the `grub.cfg` by `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` and you are ready to go!

Comment: For those new to unix, this can be accomplished by just placing a "#" in front of the line.

Comment: That's not working for me and other people on fedora 32

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once and it turned out I needed to remove a preexisting theme from the /boot/grub/themes folder because the one in there overrode the one I installed.  Have a peek in there and see if you can find anything.

Also, as an aside, you can try grub-customizer.  It hasn't been updated in a year, but it still works pretty well.

Comment: there's only one thing in /boot/grub2/themse folder and that is the system theme I'm trying to use.